# Using Google Music Manager in Linux from the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, google-music

My goal is to use Google Music Manager on a Linux server.  I'm wondering if the music manager can operate from the command line and with no GUI.  If I could set the software up to watch a particular directory on the server and upload from there, that would be the only necessary functionality.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can.

Take a look at these to scripts:

1. http://development.giaever.org/pastebin/Ubuntu/google-musicmanager/install-gmm-headless.sh
2. http://development.giaever.org/pastebin/Ubuntu/google-musicmanager/gmm-headless-script.sh
   (Visit links in direct order to understand them.)

Hope they are useful. Read comments. Remember to edit: `«GMAILUSER -p PASSWORD -s /path/to/music -m SERVERNAME»` with you own data. (SERVERNAME could be whatever. Its just a name so you can identify your server from your Google-login.)

Type `$HOME/gmm-headless-script.sh` in terminal to start sync.

Edit: some systems won't already have Xvfb installed, and on those you can fix this with `sudo apt-get install xvfb`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of "[uploading music automatically with Google Music on a Linux server](https://superuser.com/q/703168/384286)". To quote the answer I've just provided there...

I think what you appear to be looking for is https://github.com/thebigmunch/gmusicapi-scripts - a set of python scripts to upload, download or bi-directionally sync tracks. This, in turn, draws from https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API should you wish to use these python libraries for your own projects.

Comment: By far a better solution for a headless server. Easy to set up, easy to use, no x11 hacking... very good.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded my music to a headless server by mounting its music folder on a GUI-capable machine with SSHFS.  I didn't have any problem using the Music Manager to download into the mounted folder.

I know this isn't an exact solution (it only works when the GUI machine is on and the folder is mounted), but it gets the job done without relying on outside scripts and programs.